# rails ckeditor can't generate models to store uploaded files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I'm trying to the CKEditor gem running with my rails engine project. Im using the following project:

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

When running the command:

```
rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=carrierwave
```

I get the following error:

```
/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ckeditor-4.2.4/lib/generators/ckeditor/templates/ckeditor.rb:52:in `template': uninitialized constant Ckeditor::Version (NameError)
```

I have tried with both:

```
gem 'ckeditor'
```

and

```
gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'
```

Any help/support would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jon.

Comment: Have you run bundle install?

Comment: Hi, yes I've tried both bundle install and update :)